# Why does from . import views work and import views does not?

Tags: python, django

This question came to my mind while exploring Django.

Suppose this structure:

```
.
├── db.sqlite3
├── manage.py
├── mysite
│   ├── asgi.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
└── myapp
    ├── admin.py
    ├── apps.py
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── migrations
    │   └── __init__.py
    ├── models.py
    ├── tests.py
    ├── urls.py
    └── views.py
```

In *myapp/urls.py*, this statement import views fine:

```
from . import views
```

while just `import views` raises ModuleNotFoundError.

What I understand is that `import foo` searches for foo in a list of directories defined by `sys.path` which includes the current package, and also from the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html):

> Relative imports use leading dots. A single leading dot indicates a
> relative import, starting with the current package.

So, both import foo and from . foo should work quite the same. If that is true, why it isn't the case for the django imports? If it's not true, what do I misunderstand?

Answer (score 0):

there is no module called `views`.

there is no absolute path that starts with `views`.

if you want to import your views from `.views` you can do this:

```
from .views import YourView
```

Comment: There actually is views.py inside myapp. And, from inside myapp/urls.py, `from . import views` works fine but not `import view`

Comment: `views.py` is in the same directory with `urls.py` so if you want your `views.py` in `urls.py` you should use `from . import views` which means it's in the same directory but `import views` is not looking at the same directory that `urls.py` is in it.